# Custom tracking code on Woocommerce thank you page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I'm having a problem implementing a custom tracking code that pulls in order information.

Here's what I've got in my functions.php file so far, it isn't actually showing any information though when I make a purchase.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'conversion_tracking' );
function conversion_tracking() {

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$order_id = $order->get_id;
$order_parent_id = $order->get_parent_id;
$order_status = $order->get_status;
$order_currency = $order->get_currency;
$order_version = $order->get_version;
$order_payment_method = $order->get_payment_method;
$order_payment_method_title = $order->get_payment_method_title;
$order_payment_method = $order->get_payment_method;
$order_payment_method = $order->get_payment_method;


?>
  <script type = 'text/javascript'>
      window.sovIframes = window.sovIframes || [];
      window.sovIframes.push({
        trafficSourceNumber : '',
        trafficMediumNumber : '',       
        timestamp : '<?php echo $order_timestamp_created ?>',
        orderId : '<?php echo $order_id ?>',
        orderValue : '<?php echo $order_total ?>',
        orderCurrency : '<?php echo $order_currency ?>',
      });
<?php
}
```

When I try to pull the order data using this code:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$order_data = $order->get_data();

$order_id = $order_data['id'];
$order_parent_id = $order_data['parent_id'];
$order_status = $order_data['status'];
$order_currency = $order_data['currency'];
$order_version = $order_data['version'];
$order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];
$order_payment_method_title = $order_data['payment_method_title'];
$order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];
$order_payment_method = $order_data['payment_method'];
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_data() on
>   boolean in
>   /home/feratino/www/REMOVED/wp-content/themes/REMOVED/functions.php:28
>   Stack trace:  0
>   /home/feratino/www/REMOVED/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298):
>   sovendus_conversion_tracking(109947)
>
> 1 /home/REMOVED/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(323):
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
>
> 2 /home/feratino/www/REMOVED/wp-includes/plugin.php(453):
>   WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
>
> 3
>   /home/feratino/www/REMOVED/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php(74):
>   do_action('woocommerce_tha...', 109947)
>
> 4
>   /home/feratino/www/REMOVED/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(204):
>   include('/home/feratino/...')
>
> 5
>   /home/feratino/www/REMOVED/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-checkout.php(205):
>   wc_get_template('checkout/thanky...', Array)
>
> 6
>   /home/feratino/www/REMOVED/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-s
>   in
>   /home/feratino/www/REMOVED/wp-content/themes/REMOVED/functions.php
>   on line 28

Line 28 in my functions.php:

```
$order_data = $order->get_data();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'conversion_tracking' );
function conversion_tracking($order_id ) {

// Lets grab the order
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

// Order ID
$order_id = $order->get_order_number();

// Order total
$order_total = $order->get_total();

// Order e-mail
$order_email = $order->billing_email;
...
...
```